# Python: Requests url not accepting functions?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

When dealing with the requests library for Python, and entering a URL via a function, I keep getting this error:

> Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with
>   REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.

I've imported the function from another file into the file running my code. It returns a URL string and is imported, in order to use in `requests.get()` function. I've already tried messing around with the function, made sure it was importing (no misspellings, etc.).

```py
#page_scrapper.py
import requests
import bs4
from classes import image_logic # This is where I import the function from my other file.

result = requests.get(image_logic()) # For some reason this is what's causing all the issues, it won't work with a function, only with a url, period.
c = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')
```

```py
#classes.py
import requests
import bs4

def image_logic():
    return "URL string here, obviously this won't be the actual string I have sitting here"
```

I expect the `result=requests.get(image_logic())` to call the function and use the returned value as a string, but it keeps throwing the same error. Printing the URL to console via page_scrapper.py works as expected.

Any other tips would be appreciated.

Comment: It might be helpful to share an example of the return value of `image_logic`.

Comment: Good idea, I forgot to mention that I've already done so, though. It returns the exact URL string that I specified, when I print it to console in page_scrapper.py

Answer (score 0):

> Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.

This is most likely because you are accepting the webpage as bytes by using `result.content` and you must decode it accordingly, try just using `result.text` instead, if you wish not to decode the webpage.

Comment: It throws the exact same "Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER." error. I also don't see the reason to specify url as a variable for image_logic(), is there a reason for this? I intend to change the url to a variable in the classes.py file later, once I get this figured out.

Comment: @VertigoLol, its most likely an error parsing the webpage, because you are using `result.content` and not decoding it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Apparently I was trying to scrape from a pure jpg file on the site, that contained no other HTML via a link. Problem was solved once I loaded the right page into image_logic().

All came down to mixing up my links & the two looking so close that I kept missing the simplest solution.